# Is Vermivorous always level 50 (and up)?

Tags: borderlands-2

I plan on hunting [Vermivorous](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Vermivorous_the_Invincible) for the event to get some of his drops and I'm wondering, does he always spawn at level 50/52 regardless of playthrough like Terramorphous, or does he scale with the area like normal mobs?

I ask because, a la [Is there any reason not to farm Terramorphous on Normal mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/100358/is-there-any-reason-not-to-farm-terramorphous-on-normal-mode) I would like to farm him on normal mode if possible, but if he's going to be level 30 on Normal mode it's not worth it.

Will a Vermivorous on Playthrough 1/Normal Mode spawn at level 50 and thus give level 50 drops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this forum post](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=165695) and personal experience, Vermivorous cannot spawn on normal mode.  According to the description in the video below, he'll spawn at level 42 in playthrough 2 and 53 in 2.5.

*Thanks to Orc JMR for additional information*

Comment: Vermivorous does spawn in PT2, though. See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeyMcXUxz6s) for a glimpse of level 42 Vermivorous (at [3:12](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeyMcXUxz6s&t=3m12s)) and a slew of generally useful information. I cannot remember what effect this has on his drops, but the guy probably mentions that.

Comment: @OrcJMR Thanks for the info, I've edited my post to add it.